# Constraint camera movement inside an object

Tags: camera, constraints

I have shaped an object to try to define the "allowed" space for my camera. Now I'm trying to constraint the camera to its inside, but I can't make it work in spite of all the browsing I've done. I've tried the following constraints:

1. **limit distance:** seems to constraint the camera in a *sphere* centered on the origin object,
2. **Limit Location:** seems to only allow for explicit coordinate boundaries,
3. **Floor:** unsure of what it does, but I think it only limits in one direction (as does an irl *floor*... :]), relatively to the origin of the object.

I would simply like the faces of my (closed) object to behave like **walls** to the camera.

Thanks for your help!

Comment: What you're looking for is something that is sometimes referred to as a geometry constraint. Blender still doesn't have one. There may be addons that provide them, but I can't find anything online suggesting that there is even a discussion about their existence in Blender, neither actual nor proposed. :(

Comment: Wow this looks insane to me. Do you have an advice then for creating a space people can visit (like an partment for example), without being worried to go through walls all the time?

Comment: When you say "...that people can visit..." it sounds to me like you're maybe suggesting that the resulting experience needs to be interactive in some way. Is that the case? If so, you may need to employ more serious solutions, such as scripting. On the other hand, if the project is only intended to become a pre-rendered video, then you can work around the problem by simply staging your scenes and planning ahead where your camera needs to be. Once rendered, the lack of abilty to constrain cameras to wall interiors no longer matters.

Comment: Well you're right. I'm planning to use verge3D to make a web integrating app where people can visit a room, and interact with objects.
This was the initial project and I knew nothing about any 3D software. After a bit of research, I ended up going for the blender/verge3D solution, but maybe this was a bad idea? Ideally, I would like for people to be able to move freely, and not only on a track I design. This way, they could zoom in on things as much as they would like. When you're talking about some scripting, I'm curious what you're thinkg about. If you have any reference, it'd be great!

Comment: What you're describing is likely outside the scope of Blender as a standalone solution. The kind of scripting I was referring to is only the commonly used Python scripting which goes into building extra functionality through the use of addons. But you're going to need even more than that, I'm afraid, and the absence of this kind of constraint in Blender is probably not going to be your biggest hurdle. I would suggest only building the actual assets you need in Blender and then exporting them to some other development environment where all the constraint dynamics you need will then be built.

Comment: Huh! I was afraid of this! Do you have any advice on the dev environment I could look into? Thanks a lot for your answers in any case!

Comment: Since you're describing game-like development, Unity and Unreal Engine come to mind. If you want an alternative to those, consider Godot, which is a free and open source offering that works a lot like Unity.